# My friend asked me to transfer money to her overseas' family, is that legal?

Tags: money-transfer, international

My friend asked me to transfer money from my bank account to her overseas' family because she has reached her limit of overseas remittance. She transferred AUD$4,000 to my account and asked me to transfer this money for her via an online APP. I'm not sure if this is legal or not. But I do feel something wrong with it. 
Could you please help me to figure out if it is against the law? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What governing body set the overseas remittance limit?  Is this a government limit literally stopping the next transfer, is this some tax issue, is it the bank that would charge a different fee?

Comment: Is this a real friend, meaning someone you have known in person (in real life, not on line) for a long time?

Comment: Also, what country are you in and what country is the destination for the money?

Comment: This smells like a scam. I wouldn’t send a dime anywhere. And I wouldn’t even trust the $4k has been legitimately deposited, either. If it’s a scam, that deposit will bounce and you’ll be on the hook for any withdrawals.

Comment: You might get into a serious trouble if the receiver has issues or links to criminal org or activities.

Comment: Not a dupe (yet). That question is about a casual acquaintance and Moneygram limits and repeated transfers.

Comment: Too many unknown factors in the question - voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Danni - with no additional details, this question is on track for closure.

Comment: I do wish that people on the interwebs would stop using "friend" as a synonym for "some random person I've never actually met who's trying to con me out of a lot of money".

Comment: @brhans: "Using A as a synonym for B" would mean that the people who say A _intend to express_ the meaning of B. That is not the case here.

Comment: @brhans - Not going to happen. And not the best place to discuss it. That said, I agree with you. We need a word for the "friend we only know online".

Comment: @brhans These people _believe_ that they are their friends.  That is how these scams typically are successful.  I assume the scammers are good at finding the people who are quick to consider them friends.  That makes them an ideal target.

Answer (score 5):

The more important question: What kind of friend is this? Is this someone you see several times a week in person? Or is this a person on the internet that you have nice conversations with, but who you have never seen in your life?

It is a typical scam that someone transfers money into your account, you send it elsewhere, and a week or two later your bank tells you there was something wrong with the original transfer and takes the money back - you are out of pocket by $4,000, with no chance of getting that money back, and your "friend" will never contact you again.

It is of course perfectly legal to send your hard-earned cash to a scammer. Just like it is legal to give the money to strangers in the street, burn it (in most countries), or use it as toilet paper.

Comment: I think your last paragraph could be potentially misleading.  It's not illegal to send _your_ hard-earned cash to a scammer.  It might be illegal to send _someone else's stolen cash_ to a scammer; because at that point there is a paper trail tied to you.  Obviously the cash doesn't even need to be stolen, and you could be unknowingly laundering it, which still presents legal issues.